# How to hide footer (or footline) in a particular slide in Beamer?

Tags: latex, presentation, beamer

I am preparing a presentation in Beamer. I have done a few customizations to the template I am using. Now I want to hide the footline on the title slide. I also want to hide it on a few other slides. How do I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

If you want a purely plain slide, you give the `[plain]` option to the frame.

Answer (score 15):

The `plain` option is the perfect solution if you want to hide both the headline and the footline. If there are slides for which you only want to hide the footline - but keep the headline - you can temporarily redefine it like in the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
normal frame
\end{frame}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}
without footline
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
normal frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```